# SOQL not returning all results after adding new accounts

Tags: soql, developer-console

As an example, this very basic query `SELECT name FROM Account` in the developer console returns the many rows I would expect, however I have added two account records and they do not come up.

However, if I query something like `SELECT name FROM Account WHERE id = 'xxxx'` or  `SELECT name, id from Account WHERE Organisation__c='string'` the records do display.

Any ideas why the new sites would not display with the first query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the developer console, If you write a query for example

```
Select Id, Name FROM Account
```

and click on the 'Execute' button, it will execute the query.

Once a tab is open in the dev. console with queryresults loaded, if you click on 'Execute' again with the same query, it will not re-execute the query so your new Accounts will not show up.

To re-execute the query to generate new results you will need to either:

1. Close the tab and then click on execute again
2. Click on the 'Refresh Grid' button (on top of the query editor) and this should re-run the query against the Salesforce DB.

So to sum it up, if the Accounts are inserted in Salesforce, they will show up when you query for them. Try inserting the accounts, and then hitting the 'Refresh Grid' button and see if they now appear

Comment: I have reloaded the tab completely, they don't show up - but, as per question, they do show up if I search for a specific thing.

Comment: quick question, how many Accounts do you have in your org? So your saying right now, if you close all tabs on the developer console, and then execute 2 queries:  SELECT Name FROM Account & Select Name FROM Account WHERE Id = 'xxx' there is an Account that appears in the second query but not the first? I find this highly unlikely..

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what happens. Close all tabs. `SELECT Name FROM Account` returns 2282 results. `Select Name FROM Account WHERE Id = 'xxx'` returns the one result I am seeking that is NOT in the first query.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the Dev Console only shows only first 2000 rows, Try ordering the list :
do SELECT Name FROM Account ORDER BY Name DESC, and then SELECT Name FROM Account ORDER BY Name ASC. Does the Account show up in one or the other?

Comment: Another way of verifying this would be to insert an Account and then redo the SELECT Name FROM Account query. Does it now return 2283 results?

Comment: Aha, perfect, yes the 2000 row limit was the issue. Thanks. I can probably refine my query to not reach this limit but is there a workaround for this?

Comment: This depends on the context you wish to use the query. 2000 records are just what renders in the Dev Console. There are governor limits that must be taken into account (i.e, 50,000 rows returned by a SOQL query, 10,000 record DML in a single transaction, Heap Size, ....). That being said, in Apex for example, you can query (I believe) up to 50,000 records to be returned in one query and store the results in a List<Account> or Set<Account>. In your case, the result still contains the Accounts, it is just not displayed in the dev console

Comment: Last insight: I believe in the dev console, if you dont specify an order, the results will be ordered by their Salesforce ID. (Please review because I am not sure). If you want the most recently created accounts to appear on the top of the list, just always order your query by CreatedDate DESC. It is not really practical to use an SOQL without any filters applied, so depending on your use case I would recommend applying filters to query only Accounts of interest rather than ALL Accounts in your org.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The use case here is to get all sites that meet criteria to be read via the API and posted to another platform. Fortunately this particular scenario is approx 800 rather than >2000 so it's fine for now, but if I can paginate with the API then that's fine too - I just wasn't aware of it! Thanks.